# How can I join two different arrays with condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays with data below I need to alter the state in the first one to get all status in arr2 without duplication
I have provided a sample but this not sufficient at all

```
const arr1 = [{ agentId: 1234, state: "CA" }];
  const arr2 = [{ agentId: 1234, AK: "c", AL: "N", CA: "c" }];
  var res = [];
  arr1.forEach((x) => {
    arr2.forEach((y) => {
      if (x.agentId === y.agentId) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(y)) {
          if (value === "c") {
            x.state += " ," + key;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

the result should be like that

```
arr1 = [{ agentId: 1234, state: "CA, AK" }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Set` to ensure uniqueness:

```
const arr1 = [
  { agentId: 1234, state: "CA" },
  { agentId: 4567, state: "FL" }
];
const arr2 = [
  { agentId: 1234, AK: "c", AL: "N", CA: "c" },
  { agentId: 4567, AK: "N", AL: "c", FL: "c" }
];

for (const x of arr1) {
  const states = new Set([x.state]);
  for (const y of arr2) {
    if (x.agentId === y.agentId) {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(y)) {
        if (value === "c") {
          states.add(key);
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  x.state = [...states].join(", ");
}
```

Comment: yea thats nice answer but note each array size is > 22K so maybe foreach will be not sufficient, what do you think

Comment: I replaced both forEach loops with for-of loops and added a break to the end of the inner loop. The break will speed up the inner loop a little.

Comment: Can you change your data structures? For example, if you have control over building arr2, you could create a `Map` instead of an array, with the agentId as key, and everything else as value. This way finding an item with a given agentId would be faster.

Comment: yea I wish to have control over the array but I don't its come from an Excel sheet and I convert it to Jason

Comment: Do you have to run this code only once? I mean, do you have to repeat the calculation with the same arr2 for different arr1 arrays (or vice versa)?

Comment: no it's a cron job and it will be run once a day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229166/discussion-between-kol-and-mina-fawzy).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.reduce` (and `Array.find` within it to find a matching `agentId`). Something like:

```js
const arr1 = [{ agentId: 1234, state: "CA" }];
const arr2 = [{ agentId: 1234, AK: "c", AL: "N", CA: "c" }];

const arrCombined = arr1.reduce( (acc, val) => {
  const arr2Match = arr2.find(v => v.agentId === val.agentId);
  if (arr2Match) {
    return [...acc, {...val, ...arr2Match} ];
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arrCombined);
```